# Remote call ASP.Net Web Service from jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have the following problem, there is one ASP. NET Web Service project (*. asmx), with several function and is the second project, also ASP .NET, which should call a service using jQuery Ajax (no service reference).
Web Service project:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MathService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:47204/Services/MathService.asmx/Add",
            data: "{'x': '5', 'y': '10'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res) {
                $("#divMathService").text(res.d);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ALARM!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This - localhost:47204 - host web service project, when i debug project.
I specifically pointed out the full URL, something to use it in the client project.
Project works, everything all right.
The project client looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:47204/Services/MathService.asmx/Add",
            data: "{'x': '5', 'y': '10'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res) {
                $("#divMathService").text(res.d);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ALARM!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this project don't show any result, only alert, I don't understand why. Maybe problem with permission for remote call?

I can't attach project, but can send to email if someone wants to look at the project.

Comment: You are talking about a "remote call" and in case that means the server will be hosted on a different domain than your clients, your code won't work; the only way to achieve that is by using JSON-P and I think it will be hard (or almost impossible) to build it in with ASMX WebService

Comment: i recommend using a tool such as [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for debugging your ajax requests.  you'll be able to see the cause of your error

Answer (score 0):

try formatting your data as valid json first:

```
'{"x": 5, "y": 10}'
```

also, your method needs to know to send the response as json:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public int Add(int x, int y)
```

Comment: thx all! I solved this problem using getJSON() method for remote call